# unlist(base) command

Tags: r

When I executed `unlist(options())` and `unlist(options(),use.names=FALSE)` at the command prompt in r, the response given by r was difficult to understand for me.

Would any member of stack overflow explain those list of answers to me?

In the user guide of 'combinat' package of 'r', following examples are given. But I don't understand how to use them?

```
# A check that every element occurs the same number of times in each position
apply(t(array(unlist(permn(6)), dim = c(6, gamma(7)))), 2, tabulate,nbins = 6)

# Apply, on the fly, the diff function to every permutation
t(array(unlist(permn(6, diff)), dim = c(5, gamma(7))))
```

Result :[image: apply]

Comment: What is your goal? Why are you trying to `unlist` the `options()`? That seems pointless to me. What does that have to do with code from the user guide of `combinat`? These seem completely unrelated.

Comment: Your link doesn't work - it's link to a help file local to your computer. It's also not helpful. I know what `unlist` does. What I'm asking is **why** you want to use `unlist()` on `options()`? And what does this have anything to do with the code from the `combinat` user guide? Just that it's another use of `unlist()`?

Comment: @Dhamnekar please do not share code as images. Please share as plain text.

Comment: @GregorThomas, Please visit https://app.datacamp.com/workspace/preview?_tag=rdocs&rdocsPath=packages%2Fbase%2Fversions%2F3.6.2%2Ftopics%2Funlist&utm_source=r-docs&utm_medium=docs&utm_term=unlist&utm_content=run_example_in_workspace

Comment: I see all the code. **What** don't you understand? What do you find confusing? The `options()` is perhaps a bad example because `options()` is so long to make it hard to examine and understand. What about the next examples - do you understand them? If not, please explain in words what you don't understand. We don't need more code, we need something like *"I ran this <<short example>> and got this <<short result>>. I find this confusing because <<explanation of what you expected and how it's different from what you got>>"*.

Comment: And please do make your question self-contained. Post code (as formatted text, not as a picture) in your question, not on some other site. But don't post a lot of code -- keep your question focused.

Comment: @GregorThomas, Other examples are executed in my R console. So, I don't have any difficulty in understanding them. Would you explain me the result of the program code of the "combinat" package in 'r'?

Comment: Build the code up one function at a time. Run `permn(6)`, does that make sense? If not, look at the `?permn` help page. When you understand that, run `unlist(permn(6))`. Then run `gamma(7)` Then run `array(unlist(permn(6)), dim = c(6, gamma(7))`, etc. That way you can be much more specific about what you need help on.